# Questions about using Dialogs in android?

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

I'll get straight to the point. Dialog's confuse the hell out of me. Why? Because it seems as though there are 5 different ways on instantiating them, giving them a custom layout, and using them. To add insult to injury the documentation on them is very poor. so I'm going to post the main questions I have here, and hope you guys can clear some of the confusion for me.

```
Question One: 
what is the Real Difference between Dialog, and DialogFragment?

Question Two:
why is it better to use onCreateView, rather than onCreateDialog? 
furthermore, Whats the difference?

Question Three:
why not just do *Dialog dialog = new Dialog();* everytime i need one,
rather than subclass DialogFragment constantly?
```

I apologize if this thread may not seem like a good fit for the community, but please keep in mind these are very real, and un-answered questions. Of all the tutorials I've read, from slidenerd-to-vogella-to-Stack everything explains the How, but not Why, which is just as important, if not more. Thanks Guys!

Comment: I think the question is a good fit.

Comment: @Ascorbin oh, well thanks man lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The difference between them is that a Dialog can only *show* a custom view but has no means in itself for you to interact with it's views / widgets programmatically at the runtime of the Dialog (ie when it's shown). DialogFragment extends Fragment and has all capabilities and the lifecycle of a Fragment (or very similar to them when used as a dialog). 
   DialogFragment can also be used as a 'normal' fragment, which means you could use a DialogFragment to show a dialog on a tablet or have it live inside an activity (ie full-screen) on a phone.
2. If the DialogFragment is also to be used as a Fragment, it has to return a View via onCreateView, so you'll have to implement onCreateView anyway. You can probably avoid code repetition if you only implement onCreateView and not onCreateView *and* onCreateDialog. But I've never heard someone say that is is 'better to use onCreateView, rather than onCreateDialog'.
3. You don't have to subclass DialogFragment for most dialogs. To show a simple Dialog eg. asking the user a question of showing a little bit of information, you can instantiate a new Dialog() or use the DialogBuilder. I use DialogFragments only when there's some logic going on within the Dialog that I want to reside in it's own class and makes use of the DialogFragments lifecycle.

Comment: your explanation has made things a lot clearer for me, so Thanks for that! so, is the reason why both are used, is because say, an AlertDialog has a positive, and a negative button, and the user clicks on one of them. the handling of the event is delegated to the DialogFragment correct? also if i'm looking for basic YES/NO functionality then use onCreateDialog, but if i'm looking for a more complex View to prompt the user with, i should us onCreateView(), and just implement it as a fragment?